# how browsers are able to memorize input fields?

Tags: jquery, mysql, input, autocomplete

Sometimes when you input information, they have autocomplete in input fields. For example sometimes if that input field is just basic information such as Name, Address, etc, you can double click on it, and a previously added field would have suggestions.

How does that work? I'm sure its not going into a mysql database to memorize user inputs. Is it through sessions? cookies? jquery? ajax?

I hope my question is clear enough for someone's answer,

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the browser. Some store this information in plain text files, some are using sqlite.

Comment: would caching work the same way too?

Answer (score 2):

The browser stores it locally using its own method.

For instance, Firefox stores this in its own SQLite database.  But other browsers can do it however they like.

The method it does this should have no consequence on web applications as it's internal to the browser.  It may be relevant to you, however, if you are developing a web browser or browser extension, perhaps.